# Select text from linked in XML file based on the value of a specific atttribute in current node

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have this XML data file which contains the following descriptions (**XML File 1**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Labels Version="170902">
    <AppointedAs>Appointed As</AppointedAs>
    <Elder>Elder</Elder>
    <MinisterialServant>Ministerial servant</MinisterialServant>
    <NotAppointed>Not appointed</NotAppointed>
</Labels>
```

I also have another XML database file with details about publishers. Here is a stripped down example to show the issue in hand (**XML File 2**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublisherDatabase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
  <Publishers>
    <Publisher Gender="Male" Appointed="MinisterialServant" Serving="Publisher">
      <Name>Brian Wood</Name>
    </Publisher>
  </Publishers>
</PublisherDatabase>
```

Now, can you see the **Appointed** attribute in **XML File 2**? The **values** are repeated in **XML File 1** which in turn contain proper **descriptions**.

To do what I need I am currently using this XSL script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

  <xsl:variable name="PubDB" select="document('MSA_PublisherDatabase.XML')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="Labels" select="document('LabelsInfo.XML')"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Publishers Report</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Custom Publisher Report.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th class="cellVerticalHeading">
              <xsl:value-of select="$Labels/Labels/AppointedAs"/>
            </th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$PubDB/msa:PublisherDatabase/msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher[@Gender='Male']">
              <xsl:sort select="msa:Name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="msa:Publisher">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@Appointed='Elder'">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Labels/Labels/Elder"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="@Appointed='MinisterialServant'">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Labels/Labels/MinisterialServant"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="@Appointed='NotAppointed'">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Labels/Labels/NotAppointed"/>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above **XSL** is stripped down. As you can see, the value of the **@Appointed** attribute is **MinisterialServant**. It then uses this value to look up a **node** in the other linked in XML file to get the text to display (which is **Ministerial servant**).

Can this XSL code be simplified? Can I somehow directly use the value of the **@Appointed** attribute in the lookup from the other linked in XML file?

Thank you.

## Expected Output

```
   <html>
      <head>
        <title>Publishers Report</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Custom Publisher Report.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th class="cellVerticalHeading">
              Appointed As
            </th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                       Ministerial servant
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k Please see revised question.

Comment: Please add the expected output of transforming the given example.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, you can replace your 2nd template with:

```
<xsl:template match="msa:Publisher">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Labels/Labels/*[name()=current()/@Appointed]"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

---

In addition, I believe you could simplify matters quite a bit by making `MSA_PublisherDatabase.XML`the source XML for the transformation. Then your stylesheet could look something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa"
exclude-result-prefixes="msa">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:variable name="labels" select="document('LabelsInfo.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/msa:PublisherDatabase">
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- ... -->
        </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <!-- ??? -->
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="msa:Publishers/msa:Publisher[@Gender='Male']">
                        <xsl:sort select="msa:Name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="msa:Publisher">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$labels/Labels/*[name()=current()/@Appointed]"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works. Cool. I can't get your 2nd idea to work but I think I know why it fails. I won't bloat this question with the reason. I raised another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372082/including-a-xml-stylesheet-with-xmlserializer-streamwriter) Since, I use `XmlSerializer` I would need to extend it to allow me to selectively specify a `stylesheet` so I could view the publisher database properly without the need of linking it. But the answers I found conflict with the code I already have working. But that is a separate question.